# i want to append dynamic select2 with unique id each time so that i can call value from database

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter

Its' working fine with one select2 but i want multiple selct2 to fetch data from database... i am created a fucntion in model and using it in my view

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

$("#property_address1").select2({
  "val": null,
  theme: "bootstrap",
    width: '100%', 
  
  placeholder: "Select Address"
}).select2("val", null);

 $('#property_address1').change(function() {

  //alert();

  //$('#property_address').val($(this).find(':selected').data('propertyaddress'));

  $('#apt_name').val($(this).find(':selected').data('apartments_type'));
});
</script>
```

```html
<div>
             <?php echo $property_address1;?>
             
       </div>
<!--My view -->

  function property_address1()
       {
         $query = $this->db->query('SELECT host,price,city,property_thumbnail, apartments_type, contactnumber, contactperson,photographlinks,emailid, propertyaddress FROM tbl_contacts')->result();
         $output = '<select name="property_address1" id="property_address1" class="form-control">';
        
        
        foreach ($query as $row) 
        {
            //echo $row->location;
            $output .= "<option   value='". $row->propertyaddress ."'";
            $output .= " data-propertyaddress='" . $row->propertyaddress ."'" ;
            $output .= " data-host_name='" . $row->host ."'" ;
 
            $output .= " data-apartments_type ='" . $row->apartments_type."'" ;
 
            $output .= " data-city ='" . $row->city."'" ;
 
            $output .= " data-property_thumbnail='" . $row->property_thumbnail."'" ;
 
             $output .= " data-price='" . $row->price."'" ;
 
            $output .= " data-contactperson='" . $row->contactperson ."'" ;
           // $output. = $row->pincode.", ".$row->city.", ".$row->location;
            $output .= " data-photographlinks='" . $row->photographlinks ."'" ;
            $output .= " data-emailid='" . $row->emailid ."'" ;
            $output .= " data-contactnumber='". $row->contactnumber . "'>" ;
            $output .=   $row->host . ' , '.$row->propertyaddress . ' ,'.$row->price. ' ,'.$row->apartments_type. ' , '. $row->contactperson . ' , ' . $row->contactnumber. "</option>";
        }
        $output .= '</select>';
        //var_dump($output);
        return $output;
       
        }
<!--My model-->
```

`public function test($id = null)
    {
        $this->layout->set(
                array(
                    'property_address1' => $this->mdl_quotes->property_address1()
                     )
                 );
        $this->load->model('mdl_quotes');
        $this->layout->buffer('content', 'quotes/test'); 
        $this->layout->render();
    }`
When i do append it works properly but every time it giving me same id.... but select2 requires unique id to work so doesnt at second time.. Pease help me out. Thank You <3

Comment: That looks a horrendously long <option> tag! Can you show us the controller bit that processes this? Are you just missing another declaration in the controller to output to the view?

Comment: i just posted my controller up there please have a look.

Comment: So do you not want to just add `'property_address2' => $this->mdl_quotes->property_address1()` to your Controller ? and then output it on the view?